# Unable to scrape the second table from web page using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I am trying to scrape the second table "Player Standard Stats" on this web page in R: "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats#stats_standard"

I am using the following code:

```
url <- "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats#stats_standard"

xG_ind <- url %>% 
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  rvest::html_nodes('table') %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]]
```

This only will let me scrape the first table on the page, "Squad Standard Stats". Please can you provide advice on how to get the second table?

Answer (score 2):

The *Player Standard Stats* table is delivered as commented out HTML block so it will be ignored by rvest. Probably the simplest (or just plain lazy) approach would be to blindly remove all HTML comment tags from source HTML string and parse the result. In this particular case it seems to work:

```r
library(rvest)
library(httr)

url <- "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats#stats_standard"

html_resp <- GET(url)
html <- content(html_resp, as = "text") %>% 
  stringr::str_remove_all("(<!--|-->)") %>% 
  read_html()

html %>% 
  html_element("table#stats_standard") %>% 
  html_table()
#> # A tibble: 508 × 33
#>    ``    ``        ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    Playi…¹ Playi…² Playi…³ Playi…⁴
#>    <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#>  1 Rk    Player    Nati… Pos   Squad Age   Born  MP      Starts  Min     90s    
#>  2 1     Brenden … us U… MF,FW Leed… 22-0… 2000  17      17      1,423   15.8   
#>  3 2     Che Adams sct … FW    Sout… 26-1… 1996  17      15      1,336   14.8   
#>  4 3     Tyler Ad… us U… MF    Leed… 23-3… 1999  15      15      1,346   15.0   
#>  5 4     Tosin Ad… eng … DF    Fulh… 25-1… 1997  12      11      991     11.0   
#>  6 5     Nayef Ag… ma M… DF    West… 26-2… 1996  2       1       166     1.8    
#>  7 6     Rayan Aï… fr F… DF    Wolv… 21-2… 2001  13      7       749     8.3    
#>  8 7     Kristoff… no N… DF    Bren… 24-2… 1998  6       6       502     5.6    
#>  9 8     Manuel A… ch S… DF    Manc… 27-1… 1995  11      10      926     10.3   
#> 10 9     Nathan A… nl N… DF    Manc… 27-3… 1995  11      10      841     9.3    
#> # … with 498 more rows, 22 more variables: Performance <chr>,
#> #   Performance <chr>, Performance <chr>, Performance <chr>, Performance <chr>,
#> #   Performance <chr>, Performance <chr>, `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>,
#> #   `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>, `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>, `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>,
#> #   `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>, Expected <chr>, Expected <chr>, Expected <chr>,
#> #   Expected <chr>, `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>, `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>,
#> #   `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>, `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>, `Per 90 Minutes` <chr>, …
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>